# How to check if a DataBase exist or not after the connection is made JAVA

Tags: java, database, exists, database-engine

I have a big question...
I have a database java program creation.

I want to know if the database exists or not, and the if exists just connect, if not to create it.

I tried this one:

```
if (dbName.exists() == false) {}
```

THIS IS ALL THE CODE...

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
System.out.println("MySQL JDBC driver loaded ok.");
```

THIS IS A BACKUP CODE FOR IT, JUST TO WORK FOR NOW....
PARTIAL CODE THAT WORKS !

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DBurl + url
+ "?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp; + "
+ "useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8&user="
+ userName + "&amp;&password=" + password);


System.out.println("Connected to database ");           
System.out.println("Connected to the database " + url);
```

BUT I WANT SOMETHING LIKE:

```
FILE dbName = new FILE (url);
Statement stmt = new Statement;

if (dbName.exists() == true)
   System.out.println("Database exists ! Connecting ... ");
else {
   String sql = "CREATE DATABASE "+url;
   stmt.executeUpdate (sql);
}
```

I don't want to put the url with the password and username in the same place... because they are provided from an external part, but that is allready implemented and working.

So I want to rip in 2 peaces, 1 Connect "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"; WITHOUT URL which is the database NAME ... 
AND THEN IF A DATABASE DOES NOT EXISTS THERE WITH THAT NAME JUST CREATE ON.

It is not working.... not entering in the `else` more, and says that Exeption Database already exists.

Thanks you very much.

Comment: which database you are using? post your complete code and the stacktrace of error

Comment: This is not a question. It's also missing important information such as the API you are using to connect to your database, sample code, etc. Rephrase please.

Comment: *'FILE dbName = new FILE (url); ... if (dbName.exists() == true ... is not working...'* : ***Headpalm***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is a MySQL database, the following code should work. Other databases may give a different error code, but the general way should be clear. Important is that you connect to the instance, not a specific database initially. For creating the tables, you will need to connect to the newly created database. You can't use the instance connection that I use in my example for creating the tables:

```
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/",
                "root", "admin");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        String sql = "CREATE DATABASE DBNAME";
        //To delete database: sql = "DROP DATABASE DBNAME";
        statement.executeUpdate(sql);
        System.out.println("Database created!");
    } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
        if (sqlException.getErrorCode() == 1007) {
            // Database already exists error
            System.out.println(sqlException.getMessage());
        } else {
            // Some other problems, e.g. Server down, no permission, etc
            sqlException.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // No driver class found!
    }
    // close statement & connection
```

Comment: Thanks for this answers, but the problem is that I don't want with Exceptions.
I want to be CLEAN if you understand, I want after the connection to know if the database exists, and then if the database exists just print a message, and if not then:

sql = (CREATE DATABASE "+DbName);
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

Comment: Huh?! Why not? That is nothing smelly or itchy. Absolute normal.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing much about what's going on here simply trying to connect to a database that doesn't exists should throw a `TimeoutException` error or something similar.  Just catch the exception and do stuff if you cannot connect.

```
boolean canConnect = false;
Connection conn = null;
try{
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
    canConnect = true;
}(Exception ex){
   canConnect = false;
}

if (!canConnect){
  makeDatabase(...);
}
```

Enjoy your day!

Comment: Thanks for this answers, but the problem is that I don't make the connection with the DbName inside the URL. I connect first to the server and then I want to connect to the DB if exista. I want to be CLEAN if you understand, I want after the connection to know if the database exists, and then if the database exists just print a message, and if not then: sql = (CREATE DATABASE "+DbName); stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

Comment: okay... make the connection, then call getMetaData() from java.sql.Connection, then call getCatalogs() to return all the databases.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/", "root", "admin");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        String sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS DBNAME";
        statement.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Kindly Note a Two things

1. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'
2. The query *CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS DBNAME* means you dont have to check if database exits